# fatal: pathspec 'editme.html' did not match any files

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-clone, git-add

I have cloned a git public repo on Mac OSX. I made some changes to editme.html file and want to add and commit after that. But command line shows like this:

```
dips-MacBook-Pro:test-repo kirandip$ git add editme.html
fatal: pathspec 'editme.html' did not match any files
```

I created a new file locally like xxx.html and tried to add it.
Showed the same message again.

```
dips-MacBook-Pro:test-repo kirandip$ git add xxx.html
fatal: pathspec 'xxx.html' did not match any files
```

Not able to figure out the problem, BTW the repo was cloned as https format.

Would Appreciate your time!

Comment: "did not match any files" suggests you're in the wrong directory when you create the files. What does `ls` show in the directory in which you're running `git add`?

Answer (score 0):

Eventually after few hours struggling , command line routed me through this problem. It seems like this method of configuration isn't posted anywhere.

Here are the steps command line says:

```
git remote add <file.name> <online.repo.url>
//and then push using the remote name
git push --set-upstream <file.name> <branch-name>
```

Don't know why it needs this special configuration than any tutorial.
But it's working!!

Comment: I don't know why command line says after this:

          `git push origin test-4
         fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
         fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

          Please make sure you have the correct access rights
           and the repository exists.`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `editme.html`:

- does exist in the folder in which you are typing `git add editme.html`
- does exist with the right case (ie `editme.html`, not `editme.HTML` or `EDITME.html`)
- is readable (the current user with that `git add` command should be able to access/read that file)

[`git remote add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote#Documentation/git-remote.txt-emaddem) is for registering a remote repo URL and has nothing to do with adding a file.